# Extract jest.mock to seperate util function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to make a general `jest.mock` function to use in multiple test files.
The first example works when I use `jest.mock` directly inside the test file. However the second example doesn't

```js
// EXAMPLE 1
// this works
jest.mock("third-paty-module", () => {
  return {
    MyComponent: props => {
      return <input {...props} />;
    }
  };
});
test("my test", () => {
  // then assert
});

// EXAMPLE 2
// this doesn't work

// test.config.js
export function mockCustom() {
  jest.mock("third-paty-module-which-uses-webcomponents", () => {
    return {
      MyComponent: props => {
        return <input {...props} />;
      }
    };
  });
}

// file.test.js
import { mockCustom } from "../../config/test.config.js";

mockCustom();

test("my test", () => {
  // then assert
});
```

I get no errors when using `jest.doMock` but that doesn't mock my component at all.

Comment: `jest.mock` gets _hoisted_ above any other imports, your `mockCustom` doesn't.

Comment: is there any way around that?

Comment: If you want to factor out the actual implementation of the mock, see https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks

Comment: That doesn't do the trick, there is no difference if I extract it to a `__mocks__` directory

Answer (score 0):

In Jest, you can extract a jest.mock function to a utility file by using the **jest.genMockFromModule** function. Here's how you could do it:

Create a utility file where you want to store the mock function, for example **mocks**/moduleName.js.
In the utility file, add the following code:

```
export default jest.genMockFromModule('moduleName');
```

In your test file, import the mock function like this:

```
import moduleNameMock from './__mocks__/moduleName';

jest.mock('./moduleName', () => moduleNameMock);
```

Use the mock function in your test cases as you normally would.
By using jest.genMockFromModule, you can generate a mock function with the same interface as the original module. This way, you can reuse the mock in multiple test files and keep the same behavior for all your tests.